# What is the use of DataprocGetBatchOperator?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

From the Dataproc and Airflow documentation, I couldn’t get much information about what is the exact need of DataprocGetBatchOperator. Whey I tested it, it return, config values of the operator.

Please help me to understand real use pf this operator. Or link the document if available.

Comment: You get it right. Basically, the only thing that it does is retrieve the config of a Dataproc job. There are cases when you need to adjust your pipeline based on this config (file paths, etc)